# Ruby on Rails IDE for Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide

Which one do you prefer for serious **Ruby on Rails** development?

I've been using NetBeans for PHP and Java for more than year, which works really great, but the Rails support isn't imho good enough. I often have problems with code completiton, where it doesn't find most of imported gems and functions and it's also pretty slow.

On the other side, I tried **JetBrains RedMine**, which is super fast compared to NetBeans, but I don't have such long time experience with JetBrains.

Lots of people recommend **TextMate**, so I've tried its Windows port **e-TextEditor**, which I think is some sort like PSPad ... good for small edits, but not so convenient for big projects.

The last I found people mentioning is **Aptana Studio**, but I have absolutely no experience with that one.

So my question is, **which of these IDEs do you recommend for development of enterprise class applications ON WINDOWS**.

The reasony why I'm asking is **if there are any problems that you came across while using that particular IDE, that might not be obvious when someone just *tries it***

*Please answer only if you have some experience in the field, not only if you "tried it"*

**btw** I don't think this one is a dupe, since it's much more specific than those other questions

Comment: "but I don't have such long time experience with JetBrains." and "The last I found people mentioning is Aptana Studio, but I have absolutely no experience with that one.".  So, you are asking for someone to suggest a good IDE that you don't know about that you already have experience with?  This makes no sense...

Comment: I'm asking to suggest one of those that I mentioned above, but to add explanation WHY ... All the experience with those IDEs I have is only "trying", so I'm asking people who already have done something.

Comment: The main reason why I ask this, is if there are any problems with any of those IDE, that someone might not be aware at the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Netbeans 6.7 for my work.  It's much better than all the other systems except RubyMine, and it's free.  It does a good job of code highlighting in the views, and manages multiple projects well.  It also doesn't lock up when you check out a different branch (using git)

I tried RubyMine, and I liked it better, particularly the RSpec integration, but not enough better to buy a license.

I don't really use the code completion much, so I don't have the problems you describe, but I don't think Aptana is any better.  RubyMine is better at that stuff, so if that's important to you, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I'm biased, but I think you should also have a look at Komodo IDE:

http://www.activestate.com/komodo/

It has Ruby debugging and code intelligence. Using the Rails project template, it's quite easy to create and debug Rails apps:

http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/5.1/tutorial/railstut.html

If you don't need the debugger (and a few other goodies), Komodo Edit might work for you. It's free:

[Link](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/)

Comment: I've been using Komodo Edit for a little over a year to code in several languages, including Ruby/Rails. Although it's code intelligence is well behind Rails development itself, I've been really happy with it. It has the features that I really use in an IDE, but the small footprint of a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Sublime Text** http://www.sublimetext.com/. Its relatively new editor and it's available on all platforms. Many developers start to favor it instead of NetBeans, Aptana, TextMate etc....