# Rails -- IDE Recommendations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby on Rails IDE for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275258/ruby-on-rails-ide-for-windows)

I am looking for a good IDE for Ruby on Rails with the following qualifications:

1. Works on a Windows PC (if it doesn't then it's not going to help me)
2. Good auto-completion (for both classes provided by default (or by gem) for ruby and rails as well as for my own user-defined classes).
3. Good syntax highlighter - most IDEs have solid syntax highlighting (I currently use Notepad++ and it does the trick relatively well) but I would really like for the syntax highlighter to detect which language to highlight in for the Rails views (highlight HTML in general, JS inside  tags, and Ruby inside ERB tags) - Notepad++ doesn't have that capability which makes the views that contain ERB, JS, and HTML a little difficult to read.
4. Good debugger that runs when I execute my RoR app locally.

If you know of any good IDEs out there that meet as many of these qualifications as possible that are relatively cheap, that would be great!  If it is totally worth purchasing (i.e. RubyMine looks good but $69 is kind of expensive for an IDE when Notepad++ does work acceptably) then I can stomach the cost.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, as a Rails enthusiast myself. I strongly recommend Rubymine. Rubymine has a pretty neat debugger, and I would say does a decent job of auto-completion.

Give it a shot, I think you'd like it.

If you do end up using it, try out [my rubymine-settings](https://github.com/ardavis/rubymine_settings). Just go to File->Import, and select the settings.jar file once you've got it downloaded.

Comes with some live templates that I've setup, and a pretty neat color scheme I downloaded.

Comment: + for rubymine, I am going to try out your settings :-)

Comment: Awesome :) Feel free to make changes, add live templates etc. Shoot me an email if you'd like to discuss some of what I've implemented. I think you can see my email on my profile.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/cwgem/koans-tutorial/wiki/Ruby-Code-Editors) you can find a list of editors

Answer (score 0):

I have used NetBean, Eclipse & Aptana Studio. All of them are pretty good.

I havent tried these things, but might worth considering:

http://intype.info/
http://www.e-texteditor.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Netbeans, I think Netbeans a good idea.

Eclipse sometime sucks with the different versions of Ruby runtime.

Comment: I thought Netbeans stopped supporting Ruby

Comment: @kvass netbeans stopped supporting rails, so any new versions of rails will not be supported, like asset pipeline in 3.1.